# ERROR: An error occurred when reading report file '/home/vsts/work/1/s/reports/logfile.xml', nothing will be imported from this report

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am getting this error in my Azure Pipeline jobs.
##[error]ERROR: An error occurred when reading report file '/home/vsts/work/1/s/reports/logfile.xml', nothing will be imported from this report. IOException: /home/vsts/work/1/s/reports/logfile.xml (No such file or directory)

Pipelines are not failing but frequently, I am facing same error.

What is this path /home/vsts/work/1/s/reports/logfile.xml and where it located?

What actions i need to take care??

I tried multiple ways in google not found any results.

Comment: `/home/vsts/work/1/s` is the local path on the agent where your source code files are downloaded. Please check if there is any `reports/logfile.xml` in your repo. If not, please check if your previous steps created `reports/logfile.xml`. It would be better if you can share the complete yaml file or the screenshots of your classic pipeline, so that we can know what you are trying to do with the pipeline.

Comment: we have reports repo but logfile.xml is not there, we are getting error in this section.
             sonar.login=${{ parameters.sonarLogin }}
             sonar.sources=web
             sonar.language=php
             sonar.phpCodesniffer.analyzeOnly=true
             sonar.phpCodesniffer.reportPath=logs/codesniffer.xml
             sonar.php.coverage.reportPath=reports/coverage.xml
             sonar.php.tests.reportPath=reports/logfile.xml
             sonar.exclusions=${{ parameters.sonarExclusions }}         
    - task: SonarQubeAnalyze@5
    - task: SonarQubePublish@5

Comment: 1. "we have reports repo but logfile.xml is not there," - Where is your logfile.xml file? According to your configuration `sonar.php.tests.reportPath=reports/logfile.xml`, you specify the path of your test report to `reports/logfile.xml`, so that the task will try to find `reports/logfile.xml` from your current working directory. You need to change it to the actual path of your report. 2. Can you edit your original question and share your yaml file? It's hard to know your tasks from the comment above.